# Add new column to dataframe with variable length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a question in regards to adding results to an existing data frame.

```
if relevant_item != 'None' and relevant_item != 'Not in dict':
    items = relevant_item
    len_item = len(items)

    if len_item == 1:
        item_result = items

    if len_item == 2:
        two = items
        item_result = some_method(two)

    if len_item == 3:
        threes = items
        item_result = some_method(three)

hash_in_dict_shopping.append(item_result)#new list of list

shops = pd.Series(hash_in_dict_shopping)
df_final['hash_in_shop'] = shops.values
```

When appending the new list to my existing dataframe, I get an error message "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index", so I wondered how I can add the new list to a new column and fill all the missing row values with "none", whilst keeping the original order?

Original data before filtering (around 700rows):

```
'None'
'Not in dict'
['apple','banana', 'grapes']
'None'
'Not in dict'
'Not in dict'
['pasta', 'rice', 'lentils']
'None'
'None'
['milk']
```

After filtering the data for the relevant items (around 40 rows):

```
 ['apple','banana', 'grapes']
 ['pasta', 'rice', 'lentils']
 ['milk']
```

After applying some_method (returns a value from a dict):

```
['fruit','green groceries']
['dry food', 'staples', 'legumes']
['dairy']
```

New column in data frame with all 700 rows:

```
'None'
'None'
['fruit','green groceries']
'None'
'None'
'None'
['dry food', 'staples', 'legumes']
'None'
'None'
['dairy']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 points to note:

1. You should not ignore / skip over "None" / "Not in dict" rows when iterating your series. Your new series must have the same length as your original series.
2. You should use in-built Pandas functionality for applying functions row-wise. Since you cannot use vectorised functionality (as your dataframe holds `list` objects), you can use `pd.Series.apply` with a custom function.

Here's a minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['None', 'Not in dict', ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes'],
                           'None', ['mile'], 'Not in dict']})

def calculated(x):
    try:
        if x in {'Not in dict', 'None'}:
            return None
    except TypeError:
        if len(x) == 1:
            return 2
        elif len(x) == 2:
            return 4
        else:
            return 6

df['calc'] = df['col'].apply(calculated)

print(df)

                       col  calc
0                     None   NaN
1              Not in dict   NaN
2  [apple, banana, grapes]   6.0
3                     None   NaN
4                   [mile]   2.0
5              Not in dict   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting up an empty array and then changing the values if you have any?

```
import numpy as np
items = numpy.empty((len(DataFrame))
items[:] = numpy.nan

if relevant_item != 'None' and relevant_item != 'Not in dict':
items[i] = relevant_item # supposing you have some so
len_item = count_nonzero(np.isnan(items))

if len_item == 1:
    item_result = items

if len_item == 2:
    two = items
    item_result = some_method(two)

if len_item == 3:
    threes = items
    item_result = some_method(three)
```

This way your items array has the same length as the data frame and you will not get that error. If NaN array is not suitable, why not try numpy.zeros ?

Hope this helps!